# Django psycopg2.errors.StringDataRightTruncation: value too long for type character varying(200)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, heroku

Facing the above error when running the django app. What exactly needs to be changed though?
The comment_body = models.TextField() aspect most probably is the culprit since it stores reddit comments which can be of varying lengths. When i do a git clone and run it on my local, strangely it works.

[image: Heroku Logs]

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Subreddit(models.Model):
    # Field for storing the name of a subreddit
    subreddit_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    # Field for storing the time the model object was last saved
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Submission(models.Model):
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # The Reddit submission id of the object
    submission_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    # Reddit Submission URL
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)

    # Reddit Submission Title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class SubmissionComment(models.Model):
    # Parent submission object
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Text of the comment
    comment_body = models.TextField()

class Meme(models.Model):
    memeurl = models.URLField(max_length=200)
```

EDIT:

New error post char changed to 300, and migrations run locally and on heroku.
[image: New error but where is the error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the error: `value too long for type character varying(200)` you should look for model fields that have a `max_length` of 200. Since you have multiple fields with a max_length set to 200, you need to determine which model and field are throwing the error. Check the stacktrace, run a debugger and/or insert some debugging `print(instance.__dict__)`s. Once you find the culprit, extend that field's `max_length` to something larger or turn it into a `TextField`.

Comment: Thanks schillingt, found that one of the questions has 230 characters! cloned the app locally, made the changes in model then migrations locally then heroku push then migrations on heroku. Still getting a 500 Server error. Any clue what this new error means? (added screenshot)

Comment: There is almost no reason when using Postgres to use CharField. TextField is just as performant. You may just have to specify a widget for the admin and forms.